# how to enter URL in textfield like facebook and show it is valid or not

Tags: ios, validation, uitextfield

I have ipad app i want that user should enter URL in textField and it should validate and should show like facebook when we enter any url it shows some page of that web or content like that in ipad any idea how to get this i know how to validate URL but how it show it like facebook page.

Attached is the screen how i want

[image]

Comment: explain me better what you want to do. you need to validate the url and that's easy. you just create a method that check your textfield.text with a reg_exp. but what do you mean with showing like facebook? it has to show a small view with the website screenshoot?

Comment: @stabcode please update code i have added image how i want in ipad app to do

Comment: @stabcode when i enter that url it shows me below thumbnail like view of that url i want like this

Answer (score 0):

> I think you will do this in TextView not for TextField.

Some TextView do like this:

```
txt_note.editable=NO;
txt_note.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

This will detect all URL,Phone NO,Address,etc.

**OR(Method 2):**

> You can also see this in TextView Property in Xib file for TextView on
>   Right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

personally i would create a customized view to show everything. You create a class URLSnapView subclass of UIView where you can place all the elements you need. a label to show the url, one for the description, a uiimageview to show your image. you can set up everything how you like it the most.

On the textfieldshouldreturn you can place the a validation method that return a BOOL value. If the result is true, it will create an instance of your customized URLSnapView with the data from your website that you will get with your NSDataDetectorType. You can also add a UIWebView to place a small area with your website that's even viewable ;)